# Import Canva Designs into Webflow

Tags: import, webflow

So, I had wanted to make a simpler landing page for my website using Canva. Now that I have done this I am having troubles importing it into Webflow. I couldn't find much about this doing research online and was hoping that maybe someone here would have done something like this before. Is this even possible?

Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon doing more research I don't think this is yet possible. You can import your assets into Webflow but the rest has to be done manually again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to download the different sections or pages and add as image. Then you use the image and then place buttons so, when someone visit your website it will look as canva but for buttons you have to add and rest is okay